# cmd Windows operator || and && in macOS Terminal? There are some secure options to do the same?

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

In Windows cmd, I can use **`"||"`** and **`"&&"`** acting in accordance with the imposing resultant behavior.

```sh
some_command && (does_because_returned 0) || (does_because_it_did_not_return_0)
```

- Exemplifying:

```sh
date -u 1203222019 && (echo corrected date/time) || (echo uncorrected date/time)
```

Which equivalent operators to do the same are available in macOS

Or for a secured behavior, what can do the same?
Terminal for use in scripts?

Comment: Assuming your shell is bash or zsh, they are the same, but you don't need the parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bash (and zsh) have the same control operators. An example:

```bsh
$ grep foobar /etc/shells && echo foobar is a shell || echo no such shell
no such shell
```

Comment: Note that this may not do quite what you expect; if the first command succeeds, it'll run the second, but if the second fails it'll also run the third. So it's not quite the same as an `if then else`.

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe If you want the standard `if then else` behavior, then use an actual `if then else`. For this example, it'd be `if grep foobar /etc/shells; then echo foobar is a shell; else echo no such shell; fi`

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe There's a good explanation at [BashPitfalls #22](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3).